# Google Play App Signing and In App Billing Testing

Tags: android, in-app-billing, signing

I have Google Play App Signing enabled for my project, so google play is resigning my apk after upload. If i want to install my apk on the device via adb for testing in app billing, the apk has to be signed with the same key than the version in google play, but with Google Play App Signing enabled, this seems to be impossible. If i use the same apk i uploaded to google play, i get a "this version of the app is not configured for billing through google play" error when trying to purchase a product.

My question is: With Google Play App Signing enabled, how to test in app billing without upload all test versions to google play?

Comment: You dont have to upload all tests to google play, create a beta and test it there

Comment: What do you mean with "create a beta and test it there"? Currently i'm uploading the apk to the alpha channel. But while working on the billing feature i have to do a lot of testing. Therefore i don't want to upload each version but install it through adb. But i cannot sign it with the same key, the alpha version is signed, because it is signed by google now...

Comment: i had the same problem. but it went away after i downloaded the alpha APK to the device once from google play, and tried the IAP once. i then uninstalled the app, and reinstalled from android studio a build with the same versionCode, but rebuilt APK with modified actual code, and the IAP worked fine.

Comment: Found any solution yet ?

Comment: I found a solution for Game services alpha testing. Have a look at my answer below. :)

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing. But didn't want to link another app like your answer. So here is what I did:

Even though I already added my email to the testers list, I visited the opt-in link to register my email as tester. Apparently that's also something that has to be done.

After that I downloaded the alpha app from the Play Store (link is also in opt-in page). I then tried to run it from Android Studio (signed with the upload key. I haven't checked if debug key is enough). This gives the invalid signature warning and will reinstall the app. But when the app is installed you can now test the in-app purchases.

Answer (score 2):

Only licensed testers can bypass the need for matching signatures. See https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test

> License testers can bypass this check, meaning you can sideload apps for testing, even for apps using debug builds with debug signatures without the need to upload to the new version of your app.

To fully test in app purchases with actual charges, the APK must be published to the play store in any of the test channels.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a alpha testing the "Game Services", I guess, I found the solution (or a workaround).

Go to the play console (https://play.google.com/apps/publish) > Game Services > Linked Apps.

Here click on "Link Another App" and choose the same app while adding. At the end when you are authorizing this app, change the SHA-1 key to your apps debug key.

How to find the SHA-1 key in android studio?
Go to "Gradle" tab > app > Tasks > android > double click on "signingReport".

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most Android phones have a primary account, although it may not always be immediately apparent.

If you've added a company Google account as a licensing tester, consider adding your personal Google account as well.